# Demonstrate the equality of an equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, homework

I am trying to solve this problem and I have to demonstrate that the expression on the left and the expression on the right are the same. The value of g [r] has already been calculated in Mathematica and is given by:

[image]

How can I get the two equal expressions in the code I made? What command line do I lack?

[image]

My attempt at resolution:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grule = {g[r] -> -((6 f[r])/r^2) + (2 D[f[r], r])/r + D[f[r], r, r]}

A = Laplacian[f[r] (3 Cos[theta]^2 - 1), {r, theta, phi}, 
        "Spherical"] // ExpandAll // Collect[#, {f[r], f'[r], f''[r]}] &

A = A /. Sin[theta]^2 -> 1 - Cos[theta]^2

(Coefficient[A, f'[r]] // Expand)/(2/r) // Expand
(*3 Cos[theta]^2-1*)
(Coefficient[A, f[r]] // Expand)/(-6/r^2) // Expand
(*3 Cos[theta]^2-1*)

B = g[r] (3 Cos[theta]^2 - 1) /. grule
```

and

```
 A - B // FullSimplify
(*0*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
eqn = Laplacian[
    f[r]*(3*Cos[θ]^2 - 1), {r, θ, φ}, 
    "Spherical"] == g[r]*(3*Cos[θ]^2 - 1);

soln = Solve[eqn, g[r]][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
eqn /. soln // Simplify

(* True *)
```